# x86 nasm assembly - remove every nth character from string

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to implement a function in x86 nasm assembler which removes every n-th character from string. However, I am experiencing quite unexpected behaviour and don't really understand why it doesn't work.

```c
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>

char *rem(char *s, int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s[] = "abcabcabc";
    int n = 3;
    printf("%s\n", rem(s, n));
}
```

```
; rem.s

                section .text
        global  rem
rem:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        push    esi
        push    edi
        push    ebx

        mov     eax, [ebp+8] ; read pointer
        mov     ecx, [ebp+8] ; write pointer
        mov     edx, [ebp+12] ; n
        mov     esi, 1 ; counter

loop:
        cmp     BYTE [eax], 0
        jz      fin

        cmp     edx, esi
        jz      remove

dont_remove:
        ; move current character to position
        ; pointed by the write pointer
        mov     edi, [eax]
        mov     [ecx], edi
        inc     ecx ; increase write pointer
        inc     eax ; increase read pointer
        inc     esi ; counter++
        jmp     loop

remove:
        mov     esi, 1 ; reset the counter
        inc     eax ; increase only read pointer
        jmp     loop

fin:
        mov     edi, [eax]
        mov     [ecx], edi

        mov     eax, [ebp+8]
        pop     ebx
        pop     edi
        pop     esi
        pop     ebp
        ret
```

```
# Makefile

EXEFILE = main
OBJECTS = main.o rem.o
CCFMT = -m32
NASMFMT = -f elf32
CCOPT = -m32 -c
NASMOPT = -w+all

.c.o:
    cc -g $(CCFMT) $(CCOPT) $<

.s.o:
    nasm $(NASMFMT) $(NASMOPT) $<

$(EXEFILE): $(OBJECTS)
    cc $(CCFMT) -o $(EXEFILE) $(OBJECTS)
    
clean:
    rm *.o $(EXEFILE)
```

After running the code with command `make && ./main` I expected to see `ababab` (so that it removes all of the c's from "abcabcabc", in other way, removes every 3rd character). However it returns `abacb`. What is causing this issue? Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Recall that strings are arrays of bytes, not of dwords.  Your code uses dword-sized operations to access the arrays, try to change it to use byte-sized operations.

Comment: Which operations do you refer to exactly? Does it only affect the `move` operations or are others also affected?

Comment: Every operation with a memory operand pointing into the string.  For your case, these all seem to be move instructions.  Try e.g. `movzx ebx, byte [eax]; mov [ecx], bl` to copy one byte from one location to the other.

Comment: In `mov  edi, [eax]`, the dword register (EDI) implies 32-bit operand-size.  `mov edi, dword [eax]`.

Comment: If you run this in GDB, `p /x $eax` after it loads the stack arg, then copy/paste that address into `display (char*)0xffffd5d2`.  Single-step instructions with `stepi`.  You can then see the string changing as your code copies 4-byte chunks around.  e.g. first to `ababcaabc` (after skipping the first `c`, still hasn't copied the 0-terminator any earlier yet), then to `abacaabbc` the next iteration since that dword copy went out past the read position.

Comment: Note that the first 2 copies have read_pos = write_pos, so you might as well start from `read_pos += n`, `write_pos += n-1`, except then you'd have to scan the first `n` bytes of the string for terminating zeros.